# Looking for a software to design blueprint style technical drawings

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a software to draw a diagram like the one in this picture.

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/54zspv.jpg]

Comment: If I ignore the dimension lines, it looks like hand drawn to me, probably with a drawing tablet. That means it could be done in pretty much any software that supports pen pressure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in just about any drawing software (Photoshop, Illustrator, GIMP, Paint.NET).

My personal workflow would be to create the brushed aluminum background in Photoshop then bring that into Illustrator to create the line drawings.

For help with how to do that, these search terms might help: blueprint style, wireframe, or technical drawings.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally such technical drawings are made with the help of [Computer Aided Design (CAD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) software. These simulate the blueprints made by architects, engineers or designers of the times when we did not yet have computers in all offices. CAD software used to print with the help of a [plotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotter) to large scale paper sheets. This further made them look similar to a manual blueprint.

Today however large scale conventional ink- or laser-printers are available which made the plotters disappear. Still the look of the prints are traditionally imitating an ink drawing.

From all CAD applications the most well known may be **AutoCAD** or **TurboCAD** but there are plenty of proprietary, free, or Open Source alternatives:

- [List of CAD editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-aided_design_editors)

If not for engineering but only for illustration we probably do not want to learn any of these heavy weight applications. We then may get similar results with any graphic editor. Personally I would prefer a vector oriented applications to do this.

Comment: I will get a 30 trial of CAD, and see out for the result. Thank you so much.